# Executing an external Java Program from Siebel

Tags: siebel

How can I trigger an external Java Program from Siebel? The Java program was custom written, when it is triggered it does some transformation on data. I would like to execute the Java program from within Siebel, is there a way to do that with Workflows or Business Service ?

Answer (score 5):

Another way of implementing the solution is to bring the program into Siebel and call it as a Java Business Service. This methodology only works, if you have access to the source code and can invoke it. For more information on the methodology, a primer from the same author can be found here

http://www.impossiblesiebel.com/2010/04/java-business-service-jbs-tutorial.html

Answer (score 2):

Expose Java program as a web service then create outbound web service in Seibel to call it, this tutorial explains how http://siebelunleashed.com/siebel-outbound-webservice-tutorial/